# Positioning of navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have difficulties changing the positioning of my current navbar. Does anyone know what to do so it will be positioned centered below the logo? I have included a picture of how I would like the navbar to look.

[image: How I would like the nav bar to be]

```css
.navbar.navbar-default {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #ffffff;
  padding-top:15px;
  padding-bottom:30px;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #696969;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #ff9c74;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-text {
  color: #292929;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #292929;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #747474;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #ff9c74;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  color: #ff9c74;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #292929;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border:none;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-link {
  color: #292929;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #696969;
}

.navbar-brand {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

.nav.navbar-nav > li.navbar-left {
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11.5px;
}

.navbar-brand {
  padding: 10px;
}

.navbar-brand>img {
  height: 50px;
  width: auto
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-brand { display: block; }
    .navbar-bar-default .navbar-toggle {text-align: left;}
}

.fa.fa-instagram {
  font-size: 18px;
}
.fa.fa-pinterest {
  font-size: 18px;
}
.fa.fa-dribbble {
  font-size: 18px;
}
.fa.fa-twitter{
  font-size: 18px;
}

.banner {
  width: 100%;
}

.banner-inner {
  max-width:1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@media (min-width:468px) and (max-width:991px){
  .container.navbar-container {
     width:100%;
     padding:0px;
  }
}

@media (min-width:468px) and (max-width:991px){
  .container.navbar-container {
     width:100%;
     padding:0px;
  }
}


body { padding-top: 90px; }
@media screen (min-width: 468px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    body { padding-top: 0px; }
}

.banner-inner>img {
opacity:0;
-moz-transition: opacity 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: opacity 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: opacity 2s;
transition: opacity 2s;
}

.col-1-1> img{
opacity:0;
-moz-transition: opacity 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: opacity 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: opacity 2s;
transition: opacity 2s;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device=width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title></title>
       <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/icon.png"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
 <link href="css/sticky-footer.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito|Nunito+Sans|Playfair+Display" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </head>
<body>
 <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://"><img onload="this.style.opacity='1';" class= "logo" src="img/logo.png"></a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="navbar-left"><a href="http://www">TRAVEL</a></li>
    <li class="navbar-left"><a href="http://www"> PORTFOLIO </a></li>
      <li class="navbar-left"><a href="http://www"> INSPO </a></li>
    <li class="navbar-left"><a href="http://www"> ABOUT </a></li>
        </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="right"> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
      <li class="right"> <a href="https://dribbble.com/"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
      <li class="right"> <a href="https://www.pinterest.com/"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></li>
      <li class="right"> <a href="https://twitter.com/"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li> 
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!--/.container-fluid -->
  </div>
</div>
 </header>
<!---End Header-->
 <section class="banner">
  <div class="banner-inner">
   <img onload="this.style.opacity='1';" class="banner" src="img/background.jpg">
  </div>
 </section>
<!---End Banner-->
<!-- Begin page content -->
    <footer class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <span class>Copyright &copy; 2017. JH. All rights reserved.</span>
      </div>
    </footer>
<!---End Footer-->
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current HTML won't work, so I modified a few tiny things on it. Mainly just put your image in it's own div, giving it a "*margin-top: 50px;*" so that it will push down the Nav as your mock shows.   (And put in a fun logo just for fun =P. You can replace it w/ your real one.)  The reason you are having a hard time w/ this is that you also needed to override the CSS boostrap default code w/ your own for the logo.

In Desktop it now looks like your Mock. In Mobile, still looks good w/ the Logo and hamburger menu in same line. (You didn't clarify what behavior you wanted for Mobile, so I hope that's ok.)

Adding code below which I've also put in a CodePen: http://codepen.io/alejandra_quetzalli/pen/YZWMLY?editors=1100

```
img.navbar-brand {
    height: 45px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.navbar.navbar-default {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #ffffff;
  padding-top:15px;
  padding-bottom:30px;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #696969;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #ff9c74;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-text {
  color: #292929;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #292929;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #747474;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #ff9c74;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  color: #ff9c74;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #292929;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border:none;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-link {
  color: #292929;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #696969;
}

.navbar-brand {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

.nav.navbar-nav > li.navbar-left {
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11.5px;
}

.navbar-brand {
  padding: 10px;
}

.navbar-brand>img {
  height: 50px;
  width: auto
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-brand { display: block; }
    .navbar-bar-default .navbar-toggle {text-align: left;}
}

.fa.fa-instagram {
  font-size: 18px;
}
.fa.fa-pinterest {
  font-size: 18px;
}
.fa.fa-dribbble {
  font-size: 18px;
}
.fa.fa-twitter{
  font-size: 18px;
}

.banner {
  width: 100%;
}

.banner-inner {
  max-width:1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@media (min-width:468px) and (max-width:991px){
  .container.navbar-container {
     width:100%;
     padding:0px;
  }
}

@media (min-width:468px) and (max-width:991px){
  .container.navbar-container {
     width:100%;
     padding:0px;
  }
}


body { padding-top: 90px; }
@media screen (min-width: 468px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    body { padding-top: 0px; }
}

.banner-inner>img {
opacity:0;
-moz-transition: opacity 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: opacity 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: opacity 2s;
transition: opacity 2s;
}

.col-1-1> img{
opacity:0;
-moz-transition: opacity 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: opacity 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: opacity 2s;
transition: opacity 2s;

}




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device=width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title></title>
       <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/icon.png"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <link href="css/sticky-footer.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito|Nunito+Sans|Playfair+Display" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <header>

          <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div><img class="navbar-brand" href="http://" onload="this.style.opacity='1';" class= "logo" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/32877/logo-thing.png"></div>
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

      </div>
<!--         <div><img class="navbar-brand" href="http://" onload="this.style.opacity='1';" class= "logo" src="img/logo.png"></div> -->
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="navbar-left"><a href="http://www">TRAVEL</a></li>
          <li class="navbar-left"><a href="http://www"> PORTFOLIO </a></li>
      <li class="navbar-left"><a href="http://www"> INSPO </a></li>
          <li class="navbar-left"><a href="http://www"> ABOUT </a></li>
        </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="right"> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
      <li class="right"> <a href="https://dribbble.com/"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
      <li class="right"> <a href="https://www.pinterest.com/"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></li>
      <li class="right"> <a href="https://twitter.com/"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li> 
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!--/.container-fluid -->
  </div>
</div>
    </header>
<!---End Header-->
    <section class="banner">
        <div class="banner-inner">
            <img onload="this.style.opacity='1';" class="banner" src="img/background.jpg">
        </div>
    </section>
<!---End Banner-->
<!-- Begin page content -->
    <footer class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <span class>Copyright &copy; 2017. JH. All rights reserved.</span>
      </div>
    </footer>
<!---End Footer-->
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

Updated above code to also center the nav bar links/icons as requested.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device=width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title></title>
       <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/icon.png"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <link href="css/sticky-footer.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito|Nunito+Sans|Playfair+Display" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <header>

          <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div><img class="navbar-brand" href="http://" onload="this.style.opacity='1';" class= "logo" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/32877/logo-thing.png"></div>
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

      </div>
<!--         <div><img class="navbar-brand" href="http://" onload="this.style.opacity='1';" class= "logo" src="img/logo.png"></div> -->
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="navbar-left"><a href="http://www">TRAVEL</a></li>
          <li class="navbar-left"><a href="http://www"> PORTFOLIO </a></li>
      <li class="navbar-left"><a href="http://www"> INSPO </a></li>
          <li class="navbar-left"><a href="http://www"> ABOUT </a></li>
        </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="right"> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
      <li class="right"> <a href="https://dribbble.com/"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
      <li class="right"> <a href="https://www.pinterest.com/"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></li>
      <li class="right"> <a href="https://twitter.com/"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li> 
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!--/.container-fluid -->
  </div>
</div>
    </header>
<!---End Header-->
    <section class="banner">
        <div class="banner-inner">
            <img onload="this.style.opacity='1';" class="banner" src="img/background.jpg">
        </div>
    </section>
<!---End Banner-->
<!-- Begin page content -->
    <footer class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <span class>Copyright &copy; 2017. JH. All rights reserved.</span>
      </div>
    </footer>
<!---End Footer-->
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



<style>
img.navbar-brand {
    height: 45px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.navbar.navbar-default {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #ffffff;
  padding-top:15px;
  padding-bottom:30px;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #696969;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #ff9c74;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-text {
  color: #292929;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #292929;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #747474;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #ff9c74;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  color: #ff9c74;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #292929;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border:none;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
#navbar {
    text-align: center;
}
ul.navbar-nav {
  display: inline-block;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-link {
  color: #292929;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #696969;
}

.navbar-brand {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

.nav.navbar-nav > li.navbar-left {
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11.5px;
}

.navbar-brand {
  padding: 10px;
}

.navbar-brand>img {
  height: 50px;
  width: auto
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-brand { display: block; }
    .navbar-bar-default .navbar-toggle {text-align: left;}
  ul.navbar-nav {
    float: none;
  }
}
ul.navbar-nav {
    float: none;
  }
.fa.fa-instagram {
  font-size: 18px;
}
.fa.fa-pinterest {
  font-size: 18px;
}
.fa.fa-dribbble {
  font-size: 18px;
}
.fa.fa-twitter{
  font-size: 18px;
}

.banner {
  width: 100%;
}

.banner-inner {
  max-width:1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@media (min-width:468px) and (max-width:991px){
  .container.navbar-container {
     width:100%;
     padding:0px;
  }
}

@media (min-width:468px) and (max-width:991px){
  .container.navbar-container {
     width:100%;
     padding:0px;
  }
}


body { padding-top: 90px; }
@media screen (min-width: 468px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    body { padding-top: 0px; }
}

.banner-inner>img {
opacity:0;
-moz-transition: opacity 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: opacity 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: opacity 2s;
transition: opacity 2s;
}

.col-1-1> img{
opacity:0;
-moz-transition: opacity 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: opacity 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: opacity 2s;
transition: opacity 2s;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Thanks! The mobile view can stay as is. But how to I get the menu items and the social media icons centered?

Comment: I see. The reason the current code doesn't center them is because the ul is being floated.  You must: change the way the **ul** are displayed to _inline-block_. Then you can align them in the center by changing the _text-align_ style of their parent to center. I have updated the CodePen for you too: http://codepen.io/alejandra_quetzalli/pen/YZWMLY?editors=1100

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked perfectly! One last question if you don't mind me asking how do I decrease the space between the menu items?

Comment: Adjust the padding of each li > a. If you don't know how to adjust padding on elements, just google it :)